# W3 Schools validation error with POSTBACK and buttons?

Tags: postback, w3c-validation

This line of code is meant to use POSTBACK:

> `<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" />`

i keep getting these errors:

Line 73, Column 46: an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter

Line 73, Column 47: character data is not allowed here

What exactly is wrong with the code to bring up these errors???

And i have to use this particular method to get full marks.

Also with this code:

`<input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="" maxlength="20" />`

it keeps bringing up this error:

Line 78, Column 78: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

Help?

Comment: Spaces around the `=` for the first one.

Comment: Also, using `PHP_SELF` for a form action seems fairly pointless to me since the default behavior of a form if you leave the `action` attribute out entirely is to post to the same page...

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided I would say that your input tags are not inside a "container" tag. (your p's, div's, span's etc)

wrap your inputs in one of those and it should remove that validation message:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
<p> <!-- CONTAINER TAG FOR VALIDATION -->
 Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="checktest" value="on"
            title="checkbox sample"><br>
 RadioButton1: <input type="radio" name="rbtest" value="one"
                title="radio button1 sample"><br>
 RadioButton2: <input type="radio" name="rbtest" value="two" checked="checked"
                title="radio button2 sample"><br>
 Text: <input type="text" name="texttest" title="text input sample"><br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="passtest" title="pwd sample"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send"> <input type="reset">
</p>
</form>
```

Regarding your other messages, this is what the [W3C documentation](http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html#hasverbose) states about the errors you are receiving:

Line 73, Column 46:

> 111: an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter
>   Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the attribute and its declared value? Typical syntax is attribute="value".

As mentioned you should not have the space between `action` and `=`

Line 73, Column 47:

> 63: character data is not allowed here You have used character data
>   somewhere it is not permitted to appear. Mistakes that can cause this
>   error include:
>
> putting text directly in the body of the document without wrapping it
>   in a container element, or forgetting to
>   quote an attribute value (where characters such as "%" and "/" are
>   common, but cannot appear without surrounding quotes), or using
>   XHTML-style self-closing tags (such as ) in HTML 4.01 or
>   earlier. To fix, remove the extra slash ('/') character.

This one is probably because you are self-closing the `form` tag
change it to:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
```

(replace the `/>` with `>`)